# vuetify date-picker set default month

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm using the Date Picker element with a `v-model` being an array of dates: `['2022-04-10', '2022-04-11']` .

Even though my dates are in April 2022, I would like to set the default month to May (I would like the Date Picker to display May 2022 by default).

I tried with to play with `min="2022-05-01"` and `max="2022-05-31"` but still it displays April 2022 by default.

How can I display May even though my model doesn't have any date in May?

```
                <v-date-picker
                  min="2022-05-01"
                  max="2022-05-31"
                  v-model="datesTest"
                  :show-adjacent-months="false"
                  :show-current="false"
                  color="red"
                  multiple
                  no-title
                 ></v-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

`datesTest` should contain the date of May month. Hence, It will be like **:**

```
data: () => ({
    datesTest: '2022-05-01',
})
```

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    datesTest: '2022-05-01',
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker
                  min="2022-05-01"
                  max="2022-05-31"
                  v-model="datesTest"
                  :show-adjacent-months="false"
                  :show-current="false"
                  color="red"
                  multiple
                  no-title
                 ></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but actually in my scenario datesTest should not have any day in may

Comment: But if there is a dates of april month in dateaTest. Then, it does not make any sense as you want to show only may month calender

Comment: actually it's not really having dates on April, I just don't want a selected day in may (but still i want may as the default month).
I tried with dataTest = [] and setting the min and the max as in my example, but still the selected month is April

Comment: But I think there is no harm in setting `dataTest` with may month date

Comment: It will draw a red circle around those may month dates, which i want to avoid

Comment: @woshitom I tried lot of ways but did not find any solution yet. Can you please raise this concern/requirement with vuetify support. This might be a bug. I am really sorry that i was not able to help you in that.

Comment: will do, thank you so much for your time Rohit

Comment: It was nice working on this requirement. I am little disappointed that i am not able to help you on this further but once you find the solution please let me know as well. It will be a kind of learning for me as well.